# Cannot call 'operator-' with 'expr2'=input string. The argument should be of type: const integer;

Tags: operators

My code:

```
// © Crystal_Catalyst

//@version=4
strategy("My Script")
period = input("1", title="Period")
fees = input(".0025", title="Fees")
var price=close
if close>price/(1-fees)
    strategy.order("Tab Beta", false, qty=20, when = close>price/(1-fees))
    price := close
if close<price*(1-fees)
    strategy.order("Tab Beta", true, qty=20, when = close<price*(1-fees))
    price := close
```

So why does it say for lines 9, 10, 12, and 13:
Cannot call 'operator-' with 'expr2'=input string. The argument should be of type: const integer;
It worked fine when I did something similar to this in a more complex code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I forgot to set the values in the input to "defval". That is why it was not recognizing it. I wish the backtester would have mentioned THAT instead. It works now, but I have other problems. I will make another post about it soon.